# Does friction in a tube with a string in it cause the string's tension to increase?

Tags: momentum, acceleration, friction, centripetal-force

If I were to swing a string horizontally above my head with a mass on the other end, through a tube, and the tube had friction compared to the ideal frictionless situation, would it cause the string's tension to increase or decrease? Here's a visual example of what I'm trying to depict: [image: tethered ball photo]

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: i think the friction decreases the tension and causes the mass at the end to decrease in speed but im really unsure